# What are Non-linear/backward overwrites?

Tags: windows, exploit, threat-mitigation

I read some slides from the [Black Hat USA 2012](https://www.blackhat.com/usa/) conference, and I stumbled across the term 
***`non-­linear/backward overwrite`***, mentioned on slide 5 of the [Exploit Mitigation Improvements in Windows 8 by Ken Johnson and Matt Miller, Microsoft Security Engineering Center (MSEC) (PDF)](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/M_Miller/BH_US_12_Miller_Exploit_Mitigation_Slides.pdf) presentation:

[image: History of exploit mitigations on Windows]
            <sup>Image attribution: Ken Johnson, Matt Miller, Microsoft Security Engineering Center (MSEC)</sup>

According to this image, in Windows 7 there is no mitigation for this kind of overwrite, yet.

Has anyone a clue what this ***`non-­linear/backward overwrite`*** is, and can give me some additional information about this exploitation technique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, a "linear overwrite" is the most common type of buffer overflow.  This is the example given in the slide.   Where by starting at some base address you write in a linear fashion and eventually you overwrite the return address:

```
void function(LPCSTR input){
    char buffer[256];
    strcpy(buffer, input);
}
```

An example of a non-linear overwrite is this [GroupWise ActiveX control exploit written by rGod](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/24490/).  This ActiveX component has a method call where one of the parameters is a memory address, which allows an attacker to write to an arbitrary location in memory.  If the return address was protected by a canary the attacker could just point directly to the return address and overwrite it without corrupting the canary. [Dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) can also produce a condition where by the attacker can control a specific address in which to  read, write, or execute in a non-linear fashion.